# limit type variable to literal type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider this code:

```
type T<A> = {
    [A]: true
}
```

Given this type, I would like to use it like this:

```
type Obj = T<"key">
```

To produce type equivalent to this type:

```
type Obj = {
   key: true
}
```

But, the compiler is giving me this error:
 `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)`

Can I somehow prove, that the `A` type variable can only by a string literal? Something like:

```
type T<A extends ?literal?> = {
    [A]: true
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Record<"key", true>` what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. `A extends keyof any` is not exactly literal type, so we need to use mapped types here.

```js
type T<A extends keyof any> = {
  [K in A]: true;
};

// It's equivalent to built-in Record type, so you should probably use it
// type T<K extends keyof any> = Record<K, true>
```

Comment: `Record<"key", true>` would work as well

Comment: `A extends PropertyKey` will limit `A` to only valid key types (`string | number | symbol`)